# ¿Cuándo se llama el método init durante una instanciación y cual es la diferencia con el constructor?

Tags: java

He oído que había un método `init()` y me pregunté cuál era la diferencia con el constructor.

El método Init es un método predefinido para inicializar un objeto después de su creación.

Probé:

```
public class Trex {
    private int a = init() ;

    public Trex() {
        this.a = 24 ;
    }
    private int init() {
        System.out.println("init") ;
        return 42 ;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Trex t = new Trex() ;
        System.out.println(t.a) ;
    }
}
```

Pensaba que obtendría `24` pero obtenía `init 24`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método `init()` se utiliza para trabajar con Applets.

Es llamado por el navegador o visor de applets para informar a este applet que se ha cargado en el sistema. Siempre se llama antes de la primera vez que se llama al método de inicio.

Una subclase de `Applet` debería anular este método si tiene que realizar una inicialización. Por ejemplo, un applet con subprocesos usaría el método init para crear los subprocesos y el método de `destroy` para matarlos.

La implementación de este método proporcionado por la clase `Applet` no hace nada.

Tu ejemplo imprime `init 24` ya que le dices a la propiedad `a` que sea igual a lo que devuelva `init()`, esto llama al método, que imprime `init` y le asigna `42` a la propiedad `a`, luego dentro del constructor ese valor es cambiado por `24` y es imprimido dentro de `main`.

Answer (score 0):

La clase que muestras "Trex" extiende a java.lang.Object que es la clase que extienden por default todas las clases a menos que se defina una en particular.

La clase java.lang.Object no tiene ningún método público o protegido que se llame init(), por eso se ejecuta el que tu definiste.

El init() que mencionas debe ser de alguna clase en particular que tenga ese método accesible, por ejemplo java.applet.Applet.  Esa clase sí tiene un método público init(), por lo que si extendieras esa clase se ejecutaría ese método a menos que tu lo redefinas. Porque si lo redefines se va ejecutar el tuyo, y si quieres que se ejecute el de applet si lo redefiniste entonces necesitarías invocar super.init() para accesar el de applet.